# How to generate an automatic INSERT script to a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, procedure, database-trigger

I have just started with SQL Server, I don't know if it is with a job, trigger or a procedure, in short, what I need that you can support me is in doing the following:  in a database where I store the record of some requirements, which are associated to a state where they can be `Completed` or `Closed`, the requirements that are in the `Completed` state after one week (exactly 7 days) must automatically change status to `Closed`, but in addition to that I need you to perform the `INSERT` (automatic) of that record that was made, means that all the data in the row are inserted the same and the only thing that changes is the column that corresponds to state, which in this case would be finished.

The following is the query with which I obtain the records of the requirements longer than 7 days with the status `Completed`.

```
SELECT TK_DT_RECORDS.*
FROM TK_HD_TICKETS AS TICKETS
INNER JOIN TK_DT_RECORDS ON TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
WHERE TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID = (SELECT MAX (TK_DT_RECORDS_ID) 
                                        FROM TK_DT_RECORDS 
                                        WHERE TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID)
  AND (TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_CT_STATUS_ID = 'TMN') 
  AND (TK_DT_RECORDS.ACTIVITY_DATE < DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE()));
```

Until there I don't know how to perform the automatic `INSERT` into that table.

`TK_CT_STATUS_ID` corresponds to the TMN Status Identifier for `Completed`, CDO for `Closed`.

**UPDATE:**

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT TK_DT_RECORDS.*
    FROM TK_HD_TICKETS AS TICKETS
    INNER JOIN TK_DT_RECORDS ON TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
    WHERE TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID = (SELECT MAX (TK_DT_RECORDS_ID) 
                                            FROM TK_DT_RECORDS 
                                            WHERE TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID)
      AND (TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_CT_STATUS_ID = 'TMN') 
      AND (TK_DT_RECORDS.ACTIVITY_DATE < DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE()))
)
INSERT INTO TK_DT_RECORDS ([TK_DT_RECORDS_ID], [ACTIVITY_DATE], [CONTENT],[TK_HD_TICKETS_ID], [NOTE], [USER_UPDATE], [TK_CT_STATUS_ID], [TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID],[TK_CT_SERVICES_ID], [TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID], [TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID], TK_CT_SUBSERVICES_ID]) 
VALUES ..................;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done the hardest part of the work by generating a `select` query that returns the records that need to be updated. A simple way to turn it into an `update` statement is to leverage the concept of updatable common table expression, that SQL Server supports:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT TK_DT_RECORDS.*
    FROM TK_HD_TICKETS AS TICKETS
    INNER JOIN TK_DT_RECORDS ON TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
    WHERE TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID = (SELECT MAX (TK_DT_RECORDS_ID) FROM TK_DT_RECORDS 
    WHERE TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID )
    AND (TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_CT_STATUS_ID = 'TMN') 
    AND (TK_DT_RECORDS.ACTIVITY_DATE < DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE()))
)
UPDATE CTE SET TK_CT_STATUS_ID = 'CDO'
```

---

**Edit**

If you are looking for an `insert` statement instead, then you can use the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` syntax, like:

```
INSERT INTO TK_DT_RECORDS(
    [TK_DT_RECORDS_ID],
    [ACTIVITY_DATE],
    [CONTENT],
    [TK_HD_TICKETS_ID],
    [NOTE],
    [USER_UPDATE],
    [TK_CT_STATUS_ID],
    [TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID],
    [TK_CT_SERVICES_ID],
    [TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID],
    [TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID],
    [TK_CT_SUBSERVICES_ID]
)
SELECT 
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_DT_RECORDS_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[ACTIVITY_DATE],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[CONTENT],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_HD_TICKETS_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[NOTE],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[USER_UPDATE],
    'CDO',
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_CT_SERVICES_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_CT_SUBSERVICES_ID]
FROM TK_HD_TICKETS AS TICKETS
INNER JOIN TK_DT_RECORDS 
    ON TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
WHERE 
    TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID = (
        SELECT MAX (TK_DT_RECORDS_ID) 
        FROM TK_DT_RECORDS 
        WHERE TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID 
    )
    AND (TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_CT_STATUS_ID = 'TMN') 
    AND (TK_DT_RECORDS.ACTIVITY_DATE < DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE()))
```

Please note that this will only work if `TK_CT_STATUS_ID` is part of all unique keys of your table (including the primary key); otherwise you will get key constraint error when trying to insert new records.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but I do not want to update the registry, what I am looking for is to insert a new one with the same data, I would only change the status, can it be done?

Comment: @SebastianSalazar: OK, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I did not understand your update very well you can be clearer

Comment: What are the columns in table `TK_DT_RECORDS`?

Comment: Check my update based on your response, the values ​​of the insert as I get the same ones found in the registry

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do it in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a cte for this. It is just an update statement. I changed up your query a bit to utilize aliases. When everything is in all upper case it is so difficult to read.

```
update r
set TK_CT_STATUS_ID = 'CDO'
FROM TK_HD_TICKETS AS t
INNER JOIN TK_DT_RECORDS r ON t.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = r.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
WHERE r.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID = (
                                SELECT MAX(r2.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID) 
                                FROM TK_DT_RECORDS r2
                                WHERE t.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = r2.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
                            )
AND r.TK_CT_STATUS_ID = 'TMN'
AND r.ACTIVITY_DATE < DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE());
```

Comment: I do not want to update the record, what I am looking for is to insert a new one with the same data.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Perhaps you should ask your teacher for some clarity on the assignment. And perhaps revisit the logic because storing multiple rows of data for the same information is not a good way to handle data.

Comment: But if to keep a record of all the actions that are carried out for example of its change of state

Comment: Here is the challenge. What you are asking for is not all that difficult. But you have provided so little in the way of details people are blindly guessing what you want. We don't have any tables, sample data or desired results. What you seem to be describing is auditing of the data. And also a schedule job. You need a job to close the open tasks or whatever they are. Then you need the logic to go inside this job that does the work.